# SSIS CRM11 upsert record

Tags: ssis, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, ssis-2012, kingswaysoft

Can anyone help me for upserting the record in CRM11 using kingswaysoft crm connector ?

I have an excel sheet which contains employee number and other details, not any guid. I need to insert or update these data in CRM11.

Do we need guid to update the record. Can we not proceed for update without guid I mean based on employee number ? If yes then how to fetch the guid using employee number through CRM connector ?

Here need DEPARTMENT entity detail based on their name provided in excel sheet, basically need to LOOKUP. Is it possible to fetch other entities details like department through CRM connector instead of directly pointing to the sql database ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We (I work for KingswaySoft) support manually specified fields to be used for Upsert operation. It is a relatively simple configuration. You basically choose **Upsert** as the action on the general page of the CRM destination component, then "**Manually Specify**" as the Upsert/Update matching criteria. After that, you would head to the Columns page to select the matching fields which become the Upsert key fields. In the case that you set up this type of manually Upsert, you don't need to worry about GUID (and you should not map the primary key field just to be safe). When the Upsert action happens, we actually first do a lookup of the key values based on the matching fields that you have selected, it would create a new record if no match is found and our component will return the newly created record's ID in the default output. If a match is found, we use the GUID value from the lookup operation to perform an Update.

If you have to perform the Upsert based on a field from a lookup (or related) entity, you would have to go a different approach (as suggested by our team above), you would be using an SSIS Merge Join component. The idea is, you use a CRM source component to read from CRM. The source component would be using a FetchXML query that reads from the target entity by joining with the lookup (or related) entity that you want to pull the key values. After the merge join component, you would know whether a match is found. If a match is not found, then you would send to a destination component to perform a Create action. Otherwise, if a match is found, you would send it to a destination component that performs the Update action. The merge join component would be doing a left join.

Hope this helps. Please feel free to let me know if there is anything else that we can help with.

Comment: Coming back soon after applying your approach Daniel. Much much thanks :)

Comment: Daneil, able to retreive the records based on enumber (using LookUp component) and then I used update operation on those records based on conditions, branching etc.

Comment: please help me in a scenario.
I have two lookup one is JOB and another is DEPARTMENT.
When I do first lookup on JOB then I get two branch (match output, no match output).
Here, do I need to do lookup on DEPARTMENT in both branch of JOB ?
Is it good design ?

Answer (score 2):

have you taken a look at our [Help Manual](http://www.kingswaysoft.com/products/ssis-integration-toolkit-for-microsoft-dynamics-crm/help-manual#crmdestination)? You can find instructions for how to use our destination component to write data to a destination Microsoft Dynamics CRM server.

Our CRM destination component supports Upsert action, which would update any existing records in CRM if matching can be found, otherwise create a new record.

There are four matching options supported when the Update/Upsert action is selected: Primary Key, CRM Duplicate Detection, Manually Specify, Alternate Key.

You can use Manually Specify matching criteria if you do not know the GUID value and would like to perform Update/Upsert based on the employee number.

Our CRM toolkit uses CRM Web Services to communicate with CRM, we do not work directly with your SQL database.

To perform LookUp based on the name in Excel, you can use SSIS Merge component to find the Department details of the records in your excel sheet.

Hope this has helped, feel free to reach out to us if you have more questions.

Comment: Will update shortly here. Much thanks for the input :)

Comment: Can you please help with some links to get guidence in SSIS for this scenario like which specific component needs to be used to retrieve the existing records based on EmpNumber and then update records only if any difference is there between old data and new data ?

Answer (score 1):

Upsert doesn't exist in CRM 2011 so you'll need to do it manually in two operations:

1. Retrieve based on Employee number, then
2. If exists => Update, otherwise, Create

Comment: Retreive using 'LookUp' component based on sql query ? OR we can use other component like MERGE ?

Comment: Sorry I misread this originally and missed the Kingwaysoft bit.... so I'll leave the answers for them ;)